# magento - where to put templates

Tags: templates, magento-1.6

I am following the Alan Storm Magento tutorials
http://alanstorm.com/layouts_blocks_and_templates

In this tutorial he suggests creating an html template file at this location

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/simple_page.phtml
```

However templates look like they are grouped into additional directories by module name. Is this the current standard?

I am using Magento  1.6.2.  I am not sure what version the tutorial is tested for.

*** additional information ***

I created a file called "local.xml" at this location
app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/local.xml

that contains:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="simple_page.phtml" />                         
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

then file "simple_page.phtml" in directory:

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/

that contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>    
</head>
<body>
    <p>hello world</p>
</body>
</html>
```

After clearing cache, I get "white screen of death" on home page, however helloworld page works.

If I erase local.xml, front page comes back.

Comment: Stony - I am not adding a default theme.  I am following tutorial on "Layouts, Blocks and Templates". I will add more details to question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short [Turorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/working-with-magento-themes) but the main concept is that you make your own **theme/template** and overwrite the default templates.

So you can create under **System -> configuration -> Design** under the point **Theme** you change the default to your own theme name like "my_theme".

Rest you can see in the tutorial. You can put a folder with your theme name to

```
app\code\frontend\default\my_theme
```

Then you can copy the template from default with the same folder structure to your theme and magento take the template from your theme folder instead the default template.

Answer (score 0):

Keep reading the tutorial...
http://alanstorm.com/layouts_blocks_and_templates

"If you go to any other page in your Magento site, you’ll notice
 they’re either blank white, or have the same red background that your
 hello world page does. Let’s change your local.xml file so it only
 applies to the hello world page. We’ll do this by changing default to
 use the full action name handle (helloworldindexindex)."

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <helloworld_index_index>
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="simple_page.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </helloworld_index_index>
</layout>
```